# Specifying relative path to shockwave flash object

Tags: asp.net, winforms, c#-4.0, axshockwaveflash

While playing the .SWF file in windows forms as below, I noticed that it doesn't takes any relative paths.

What is done below is that each time the PlayVideo Form Dialog opens it loads a new video which I was tracking using a global variable: `GlobalVariablesTracking.videoTrack` and incremented it after successfully loading a video.

```
private void PlayVideo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   CurrentVideoKey = GlobalVariablesTracking.videoTrack;
   currentVideoName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[CurrentVideoKey.ToString()];

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentVideoName))
   {
     GlobalVariablesTracking.videoTrack = GlobalVariablesTracking.videoTrack + 1;
    axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "\\Videos\\" + currentVideoName;
    axShockwaveFlash1.Play();                
   }
 }
```

Below are the Keys I read from `App.Config`

```
<add key="1" value="a.swf"/>
<add key="2" value="b.swf"/>
.....
```

The issue I encountered in the line:

```
axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "\\Videos\\" + currentVideoName;
```

It doesn't takes  relative path. If a complete absolute path is specified as below, it works perfectly.

```
axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "C:\\Videos\\" + currentVideoName;
```

**How to get this ShockWave flash object to work with a Relative URL ?**

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working.

The solution was to use `Application.StartupPath` and append to it the rest of your relative path.

```
axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = Application.StartupPath +"\\Videos\\"+ currentVideoPath;
```

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx) was really helpful.